# Сортировка по первой букве / цифре

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

Столкнулась с такой задачей. В текстовом файле имеются строки такого типа:

```
Беляев Антон Степанович 19.08.1986
Алексеев Денис Владимерович 20.06.1980
Еврошина Анна Петровна 30.07.1975
Belyaev Anton Stepanovich 08/19/1986
Alexeev Denis Vladimirovich 06.20.1980
Evroshina Anna Petrovna 07/30/1975
3.Belyaev Anton Stepanovich 08/19/1986
2.Alexeev Denis Vladimirovich 06.20.1980
1.Evroshina Anna Petrovna 07/30/1975
```

**Вот вопрос:** Как отсортировать список этих строк **в алфавитном порядке**.Что бы **на выходе получился результат** (если есть номера в списке то сортировать просто по возрастанию). То есть так:

```
1.Evroshina Anna Petrovna 07/30/1975
2.Alexeev Denis Vladimirovich 06.20.1980
3.Belyaev Anton Stepanovich 08/19/1986
Alexeev Denis Vladimirovich 06.20.1980
Belyaev Anton Stepanovich 08/19/1986
Evroshina Anna Petrovna 07/30/1975
Алексеев Денис Владимерович 20.06.1980
Беляев Антон Степанович 19.08.1986
Еврошина Анна Петровна 30.07.1975
```

**Хотела бы добавить:** Сложность в том что, в одном текстовом файле, фамилии как на русском так и на английском + попадаются строки где идет нумерация фамилия имя отчество. По этому я и не могу справится с этой задачей :(. Может есть какие функции или варианты решение такой задачи или это не решаемая задача ?. Заранее благодарна за помощь...

**Мои попытки сделать функцию сортировки по возрастанию:**

```
var
 sl: TStringList;
 i: Integer;

function Compare(List: TStringList; Index1, Index2: Integer): Integer;
begin
 if List[Index1] > List[Index2] then
   Result := +1
 else if List[Index1] < List[Index2] then
   Result := 1
 else
   Result := 0;
end;

begin
 sl := TStringList.Create;
 sl.CustomSort(Compare);
 for i := 0 to sl.Count - 1 do
   WriteLn(sl[i]);
 sl.Free
end.
```

Comment: Татьяна, здравствуйте. Вы меня удивляете. Что здесь такого "нерешаемого"? Передавайте в метод `Sort` свою функцию сравнения строк, а в ней пишите логику, которая Вам нужна.

Comment: @Igor, Здравствуйте. Не поймите меня неправильно, но я добавила в тему мои наработки. Это пока все что пришло мне в голову.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[StrCmpLogicalW](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/desktop/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-strcmplogicalw) - функция сравнения строк, которая рассматривает цифры как числа, а не как строки.

Пример использования:

```
uses
  Winapi.ShLwApi,
  System.Generics.Defaults,
  System.Generics.Collections,
  System.SysUtils;

var
  VItem: string;
  VItems: array [0..8] of string = (
    'Беляев Антон Степанович 19.08.1986',
    'Алексеев Денис Владимерович 20.06.1980',
    'Еврошина Анна Петровна 30.07.1975',
    'Belyaev Anton Stepanovich 08/19/1986',
    'Alexeev Denis Vladimirovich 06.20.1980',
    'Evroshina Anna Petrovna 07/30/1975',
    '3.Belyaev Anton Stepanovich 08/19/1986',
    '2.Alexeev Denis Vladimirovich 06.20.1980',
    '1.Evroshina Anna Petrovna 07/30/1975'
  );
begin
    TArray.Sort<string>(VItems, TDelegatedComparer<string>.Construct(
      function(const Left, Right: string): Integer
      begin
        Result := StrCmpLogicalW(PChar(Left), PChar(Right));
      end)
    );

    for VItem in VItems do begin
      Writeln(VItem);
    end;

    Readln;
end.
```

Comment: Благодарна Вам за помощь но у меня база 30-40 тысяч строк, в среднем. И разве при таком варианте получиться отсортировать ?

Comment: @Татьяна Получится. 40 тыс строк по ~80 символов (2 байта на символ) это же всего 6 Мб оперативки надо. Мелочь, по современным меркам.

Comment: Да, только что попробовала метод Dima (Дмитрия). И действительно выходит что если поставить 20.Alexeev Denis Vladimirovich 06.20.1980 то неправильно сортирует именно с цифрами. Сейчас буду пробовать с вашим алгоритмом разобраться.

Comment: Только не могу разобраться почему  у меня пишет: undeclared identifier выделяя StrCmpLogicalW в Uses я все прописала...

Comment: @Татьяна Возможно, в вашей версии Delphi в юните `ShLwApi` эта функция не объявлена. В таком случае, используйте такое объявление: `function StrCmpLogicalW(psz1, psz2: PWideChar): Integer; stdcall; external 'shlwapi.dll';` А лучше, обновите Delphi до текущей актуальной версии (10.2.3).

Comment: Все, только что разобралась. Теперь все работает, спасибо Вам и Всем (человеческое) кто помог в этой теме. Приятного рабочего дня!

Comment: Отличный ответ! Каюсь, с `CustomSort` я так и не совладал(( Зато узнал про `StrCmpLogicalW` ;)

Comment: Огромное Вам спасибо! Сколько сортировочных велосипедов я теперь могу разобрать благодаря StrCmpLogicalW :) (даже не догадывался о существовании такой прелестной функции)

Comment: @kami Строго говоря, эта функция всё же не панацея и не во всех случаях она сортирует как хотелось бы. Для задачи в данном вопросе, этой функции вполне достаточно, но я в своих проектах пользуюсь кодом из этой статьи: [Сортировка списка по аналогу «Проводника Windows»](https://habr.com/post/181760/). Там же, приводится показательный случай, когда `StrCmpLogicalW` лажает (сортировка строк `000`, `00`, `0`).

Answer (score 1):

Вот такой вариант решения проблемы. Что называется "в лоб".

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  List: TStringList;
Begin
  List := TStringList.Create;
  try
    // Загружаем данные
    List.Add('Беляев Антон Степанович 19.08.1986');
    List.Add('Алексеев Денис Владимерович 20.06.1980');
    List.Add('Еврошина Анна Петровна 30.07.1975');
    List.Add('Belyaev Anton Stepanovich 08/19/1986');
    List.Add('Alexeev Denis Vladimirovich 06.20.1980');
    List.Add('Evroshina Anna Petrovna 07/30/1975');
    List.Add('3.Belyaev Anton Stepanovich 08/19/1986');
    List.Add('2.Alexeev Denis Vladimirovich 06.20.1980');
    List.Add('1.Evroshina Anna Petrovna 07/30/1975');

    // Сортировка
    List.Sort;

    // Показываем результат
    for i:=0 to List.Count - 1 do
      ShowMessage(List.Strings[i]);
  finally
    List.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Уверен, что можно найти более элегантный способ решения, но если время дорого (а иначе не бывает), то я бы использовал такой подход.

Comment: Ну а если база большая ? :(

Comment: @Татьяна, насколько большая? 100 строк? 10 тысяч? Миллион?

Comment: 30-40 тысяч в среднем.

Comment: @Татьяна, если исходные данные у Вас на руках - почему бы не опробовать предложенный мной вариант и замерить время выполнения. Не думаю, что выйдет более 10 секунд (приблизительное значение, ибо зависит от характеристик машины на которой будет производиться работа).

Comment: @Dima Вместо `2.Alexeev..` напишите `20.Alexeev..` и увидите, что дефолтная сортировка - это не то, что нужно.

Comment: @zed, верно! Некорректно выходит. Надо почитать про [CustomSort](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Classes_TStringList_CustomSort.html)